# ModalNavigationDrawer not navigating to another screen after clicking an item in ModalDrawerSheet

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm having an issue with ModalNavigationDrawer. It is supposed to navigate to another screen after clicking an item in the ModalDrawerSheet, but it does nothing. Here are my files:

TaskListEvent.kt

```
sealed class TaskListEvent {
    data class OnDeleteTask(val task: Task) : TaskListEvent()
    object OnUndoDeleteTask : TaskListEvent()
    data class OnEditClick(val task: Task) : TaskListEvent()
    object OnAddTask : TaskListEvent()
    class OnDrawerNavigationClick(val navigationItem: NavigationItem) : TaskListEvent()
}
```

Routes.kt:

```
sealed class Routes(val route: String) {
    object TASKSLIST : Routes(route = "tasks_list")
    object ADDEDITTASK : Routes(route = "add_edit_task")
}
```

Navigation.kt:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@Composable
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.TASKSLIST.route) {
        composable(
            Routes.TASKSLIST.route
        ) {
            TasksListScreen(onNavigate = {
                navController.navigate(it.route)
            })
        }
        composable(
            route = Routes.ADDEDITTASK.route + "?taskId={taskId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(name = "taskId") {
                type = NavType.IntType
                defaultValue = -1
            })
        ) {
            AddEditScreen(
                onPopBackStack = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                })
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationItem.kt:

```
data class NavigationItem(
    val title: String,
    val selectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val unselectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val route: String
)

val items = listOf(
    NavigationItem(
        title = "Planner",
        selectedIcon = Icons.Default.Done,
        unselectedIcon = Icons.Default.Done,
        route = Routes.TASKSLIST.route
    ),
    NavigationItem(
        title = "Library",
        selectedIcon = Icons.Default.Email,
        unselectedIcon = Icons.Default.Email,
        route = Routes.ADDEDITTASK.route
    )
)
```

TaskListViewModel.kt:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TaskListViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: TaskRepositoryImplementation) :
    ViewModel() { [...]
            is TaskListEvent.OnDrawerNavigationClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(event.navigationItem.route))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }
}
```

TasksList.kt:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TasksListScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
    viewModel: TaskListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val tasks = viewModel.tasks.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val snackBarController = SnackBarController(coroutineScope)
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collectLatest { event ->
            when (event) {
                [...]

                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    onNavigate(event)
                }

                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    ModalNavigationDrawer(drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
                NavigationDrawerItem(
                    label = { Text(item.title) },
                    selected = index == selectedItemIndex,
                    onClick = {
                        TaskListEvent.OnDrawerNavigationClick(item)
                        selectedItemIndex = index
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            drawerState.close()
                        }
                    },
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = if (index == selectedItemIndex) {
                                item.selectedIcon
                            } else item.unselectedIcon, contentDescription = item.title
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding))
            }
        }
    }, drawerState = drawerState) { [...] }
```

I have tried to change the route type from "string" to actual "route" type in NavigationItem.kt and make the needed changes in the TaskListViewModel.kt:

replaced `sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(event.navigationItem.route))`
with `sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(event.navigationItem.route.toString()))`

but nothing seemed to work anyway. Do you have any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: What is your `NavigationDrawerItem`'s `onClick` supposed to be doing? It looks like it creates an event object, but then doesn't actually do anything with it?

Comment: It is supposed to navigate to another route. To my mind In the ```TasksList.kt``` it navigates to the route with the corresponding item. In the ```TaskListViewModel.kt``` I have specified the navigation. I know there is a logic problem, but I don't seem to catch it

Comment: But you don't actually do anything with the event you created? How does it get to something that actually calls navigate?

Comment: To my understanding, the ```onClick``` triggers the ```OnDrawerNavigationClick``` with the specific item of the ModalDrawerSheet, which is used in the ```TaskListViewModel.kt``` to determine where it should navigate. I don't really get how it doesn't do anything with it when I have specified the function ```Navigate``` in ```UiEvent.kt```

Comment: Your `onClick` seems to create a `OnDrawerNavigationClick` event object, but how does it get into the `viewModel.uiEvent` for you to actually *do* something with it?

Comment: I see now, I'm an idiot haha. I appreciate your patience and guiding me, not actually giving the answer straight away. If you want to gain points you can write the answer and I will mark it if not I shall delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `TaskListEvent.OnDrawerNavigationClick(item)`, you're creating an event, but you're not actually doing anything with that event - it never makes it to your `viewModel.uiEvent` flow to actually get processed. You'll need to connect these two pieces together if you want to process the event from the click.